# What happens when a React component is bound to a Mobx observable store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a React component.

```
@observer
export default class Tree extends Component
```

It is bound to an observable store

```
class TreeStore {
  @observable nodes;
}
```

An instance of TreeStore is passed to the React component as a store. So, the render method is as follows.

```
render() {
  const { store } = this.props;
  // render the nodes within the store
}
```

Everything works as expected when I pass the store to the Tree component as a prop. But, when I pass in a new store object to the Tree component (a new instance), the Tree component is not re-rendered or refreshed.

The container component looks something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Select value={this.param} onChange={this.handleParamChange} />
      <Tree store={this.store} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And handleParamChange creates a new store based on change to the dropdown.

```
handleParamChange() {
  this.store = createAnotherStore(); // store is also observable!
}
```

I like to know what is happening behind the scenes. What happens when a React component (observer) is bound to a Mobx observable store? What causes the re-render to happen? If I pass it a new store, how do I rebind the component?

I walked through [mobx-react/observer](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/src/observer.js) code. Lifecycle events are attached to the component. And componentWillMount does quite a lot of things. But not able to figure out which objects are being observed !!!. (initialRender / reactiveRender). If I send a new store in the prop, will that get observed as well?

### UPDATE

Mobx works as expected. If a new store is passed as a prop, the observables continue to trigger re-renders. I had a few issues in my code. After some fixes, the code works alright. I am going to close this question. I am not deleting it. Because, if someone has similar issues, the problem is with their code and not Mobx. Hope it helps.

Comment: An observer React component is re-rendered when the observables it dereferenced in the last render are changed. Do you have the options of including your render code in the question? That would help a lot.

Comment: @Tholle added container component render

Comment: Have you tried using [**extendObservable**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html)?  `extendObservable(this, { store: createAnotherStore() });`

Comment: It would be helpful if you reproduced this in a CodePen or JsFiddle project.

Comment: I tried to reproduce in a minimal example: Mobx boilerplate. I could not reproduce it. Mobx works fantastic, as expected. I did a code walk through of my code, which is much more complex than outlined here. Fixed the problem. I voted to close the question to avoid others trying to answer it. Thanks.